# In macOS, how can I add a custom menu item in the Application menu?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, user-interface, wxpython

I need to add a *Check for Updates* menu item in an app. In Windows, this menu item is usually placed in the Help menu, so no problem here. My problem is that in macOS the menu item is placed (not always but usually) in the Application menu and I have no idea about how to add a custom menu item the Application menu.

Find below some code to play around. So, how do I move the Check for Updates menu item from the Help menu to the Application menu in macOS?

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Menu item in macOS Application menu')

        self.MyMenu()
    #---

    def MyMenu(self):
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()

        Helpmenu = wx.Menu()
        Helpmenu.Append(301, 'Manual')
        Helpmenu.Append(302, 'Tutorials')
        Helpmenu.Append(303, 'Check for Updates')

        menubar.Append(Helpmenu, '&Help')

        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can append custom items into the App Menu; nothing I've seen indicates otherwise. Maybe the reason for this is that Windows doesn't have an App Menu like macOS so only standard ID's can be implemented — just speculation though...